# What is start_wqthread? Does it affect the UIMainThread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

[image]

I am using instrument (time profile) to analyze an app. In this figure, what does the start_wqthread mean?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The "wq" in `start_wqthread` stands for "work queue".  It's the entry point for any thread started by GCD.  It has no impact on the main thread, other than using hardware resources, same as any other code.

Comment: clear explanation. Thanks. will accept it after required minutes.

Comment: Judging from http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.40.1/i386/pthreads/start_wqthread.s this is a function in the pthread library (and GCD uses pthreads).

Comment: While that may be more precise, my answer is still accurate.